# javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' (или '==')

Tags: javascript, php, tpl

В коде

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dNumber = {$smarty.session.s_dNumber};
</script>
```

выскакивает ошибка: ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'***
Очевидно, из-за того, что переменная в сессии пустая либо отсутствует (?).
Пытаюсь эту ситуацию обойти:

```
    var dNumber = {$smarty.session.s_dNumber} == '' ? :{$smarty.session.s_dNumber};
```

Ошибка слегка меняется: ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=='***

Код - часть проекта, проверять который на адекватность нереально.
Как справиться с этой ситуацией в пределах моего участка кода?

P.S. код - вставка JS в *.tpl файле для PHP-обработки

Comment: это у вас php или что?

Comment: вставка JS в *.tpl файле для PHP-обработки

Comment: а смотрели, как получившийся код выглядит?

Comment: @ThisMan `var dNumber = ;`

Comment: @ThisMan, да. фактически об этом и написал: "Очевидно, из-за того, что переменная в сессии пустая либо отсутствует (?)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dNumber = '{$smarty.session.s_dNumber}';
```

---

Код преобразования шаблона (template-а) срабатывает независимо от того, поставили мы кавычки или нет, и выводит значение `s_dNumber` в соответствующее место получившегося текста. Если значение `s_dNumber` - пустая строка, или его нет, то получается синтаксически неверный JS:

```
var dNumber = ;
```

Соответственно, при наличии кавычек:

```
var dNumber = '';
```

Если `s_dNumber` - число, и Вы хотите, чтобы JS-переменная `dNumber` тоже была числом, то можно написать

```
var dNumber = Number('{$smarty.session.s_dNumber}');
```

или даже без кавычек

```
var dNumber = Number({$smarty.session.s_dNumber});
```

Тогда для пустого `s_dNumber` `dNumber` будет равно нулю.

Comment: не ожидал, но похоже, вы правы. спасибо. сам такой вариант не проверял, т.к. ожидал бы вставку строки. буду также благодарен за пояснение почему произошло присвоение не строки, а переменной

Comment: @SimplyOne Код преобразования шаблона (template-а) срабатывает независимо от того, поставили мы кавычки или нет, и выводит значение `s_dNumber` в соответствующее место получившегося текста. Если значение `s_dNumber` - пустая строка, или его нет, то получается синтаксически неверный JS. Если `s_dNumber` - число, и Вы хотите, чтобы JS-переменная `dNumber ` тоже была числом, то можно написать `var dNumber = Number('{$smarty.session.s_dNumber}');` или даже без кавычек `var dNumber = Number({$smarty.session.s_dNumber});`. Тогда для пустого `s_dNumber` `dNumber` будет равно нулю.

Comment: супер. спасибо!